# Positioning of divs, when creating a HTML/CSS only treemap

Tags: html, css, treemap

I am fairly new to CSS, but I want to know if there's an easier way to order these boxes, as I need something like a treemap, which links to a certain page, as you can see, have some animations. Currently I want to order this third box below the second one, and I don't know how, I'm trying with float and clear, but doesn't work for me. Excuse my beginner knowledge, but I'm learning. Also, if there's an easier way to do this, except manually like I'm doing, let me know please.

```css
    .cbox1 {
    border:solid 2.5px white;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    z-index: 10;
    }

    .cboxtext {
    text-align:center;
    height:50%;
    margin-top: 200px;
    color:#fff;
    }

    .cboxpercentage {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:80px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#fff;
    margin-top: -300px;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="#">
        <div class="cbox1 hvr-bounce-out" style="width:400px; height:400px;background-color:steelblue;">
         <h2 class="cboxtext"> Company 1 </h2>
         <h1 class="cboxpercentage"> 62,5% </h1>
            </div></a>
     <a href="#">
    <div id="wrapper">
     <div class="cbox1 hvr-sink" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:dodgerblue;">
         <h2 class="cboxtext" style="font-size:24px; margin-top:90px;"> Company 2 </h2>
         <h1 class="cboxpercentage"> 32,5% </h1>
            </div></a>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="cbox1 hvr-float" style="width:200px; height:200px; background-color:blue;">
                <h2 class="cboxtext"> Company 3 </h2>
                <h1 class="cboxpercentage"> 5% </h1>
            </div>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: search for jquery and treeview, lots of examples

Comment: You have your headings the wrong way around - `h2`s should follow `h1`.  They should be used to mark section headers and not for styling purposes.  Also you open a wrapper div inside an `a` tag but close it outside - this is invalid markup

Comment: [This will give you](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/primers/html/article.php/3894911) an example of how to create a simple nav structure and then there are a lot of examples out there how to style it

Comment: An image of what this is supposed to look like would be useful.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want to create somethiing like the interactive treemap they have here on this page, because I'm creating a site, that will announce like the best companies of 2015 in every sector - http://www.bloomberg.com/graphics/2015-bschool-choices/

Comment: That's built with Javascript so the answer would be very broad.

Comment: @Paulie_D I figured that out, but my JS knowledge isn't that good, so I tried to make a static treemap.

Comment: If you're using floats etc you need to break down the final look into logical rows and columns...then build from there, Bearing in mind that the specific look you are after *may not be possible using floats*. So...we need to see what your desired result should look like...

Comment: @revetinja, first answer is correct i think :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a new version of your code:

```css
    .cbox1,#wrapper {
        position: relative;
    }
    .cbox1 a,#wrapper a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
    }
    .cbox1 a span,#wrapper a span {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        line-height: 400px;
    }

    .cbox1 a span.cboxtext,#wrapper a span.cboxtext {
        line-height:30px;
    }

    .cbox1 {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        float: left;
    }

    a .cboxtext {
        top: 10px;
        text-align:center;
        color:#fff;
    }

    .cboxpercentage {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:80px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color:#fff;
    }

    #wrapper {
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #wrapper a span {
        line-height: 200px;
    }

    #wrapper .cbox1 {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #wrapper .cbox1 a {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }

    #wrapper .cboxpercentage {
        font-size:40px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="cbox1 hvr-bounce-out" style="background-color:steelblue;">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="cboxtext">Company 1</span>
        <span class="cboxpercentage"> 62,5% </span>
    </a>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="cbox1 hvr-sink" style="background-color:dodgerblue;">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="cboxtext">Company 2</span>
            <span class="cboxpercentage">32,5%</span>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="cbox1 hvr-float" style="background-color:blue;">
        <a href="#">
            <span class="cboxtext">Company 3</span>
            <span class="cboxpercentage">5%</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```